# How do I read in an array of characters and convert to an integer in C with error checking?

Tags: c, fgets

I'm trying to read user input into a character array in C and convert it to an integer.Here is my approach, I want to make sure the user can't enter more than 255 characters. I'm not sure if declaring a fixed sized array and using fgets will handle this for me.

Also isn't it redundant to put 255 in fgets when I've already fined user_input will be an array of size 255?

Here is my approach, is there a better way to do this?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char user_input[255]; 
  int num_entered;

  fgets(user_input,255, stdin);
  num_entered = atoi(user_input);

  printf("Number entered is: %d\n", num_entered);
}
```

Comment: You can't stop the user entering more than 255 characters (unless you take away their keyboard). What you can do is make sure you don't overflow your buffers by reading more than 255 characters. Which you are already doing. So not sure what other "error checking" you are referring to. Please clarify.

Comment: "isn't it redundant to put 255 in fgets". No it's not. Just like it's not redundant to tell someone your name even though it is already defined on your birth certificate. `fgets` cannot get the size itself.

Comment: Your question is not relevant in stack overflow you should post it at code review. With an array you can do `fgets(user_input, sizeof user_input, stdin);`. you should look what return `fgets()` and you should declare `num_entered` when you init it so `int num_entered = atoi(user_input);`.

Comment: It would be better to use `strtol()` instead of `atoi()`.

Comment: `fgets` already provides error checking, use it. `atoi` has no error checking, use `strtol` instead.

Comment: Allocating an array of 255 characters is a waste. Most modern C compilers allocate memory in words, not bytes. You will get 256 bytes, anyway.

Comment: Yes, error checking is the wrong word, I just want to make sure the buffer doesn't overflow.
Also I don't know what code review is, could you explain where I can find that? I'm a new user as you can tell. I didn't know this isn't a relevant question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that will help you check errors with `fgets()` and `strtol()`. Alot of the error checking for `strtol()`, as recommended in the comments, is from the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html), which is always a good place to look when learning new functions.

In regards to checking for buffer overflow, you need to check if the last valid character is a `\n`, then if it is, replace it with a null terminator. If its not, then their is buffer overflow.

### Example Code:

**Note:** Probably better to abstract these ideas into functions, but this should help you get started.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 255
#define BASE 10

int main(void) {
    char user_input[BUFFSIZE];
    char *endptr;
    long num_entered;
    size_t slen;

    printf("Enter string: ");

    /* fgets() returns NULL on error */
    if (fgets(user_input, BUFFSIZE, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf("Error reading buffer.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* removing '\n' character, and checking for overflow */
    slen = strlen(user_input);
    if (slen > 0) {
        if (user_input[slen-1] == '\n') {
            user_input[slen-1] = '\0';
        } else {
            printf("Exceeded buffer size of %d.\n", BUFFSIZE);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* checking is something useful was entered */
    if (!*user_input) {
        printf("No user input entered.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    errno = 0;
    num_entered = strtol(user_input, &endptr, BASE);

    /* error checking for strtol() */
    if (endptr == user_input) {
        printf("No digits parsed from input.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* validating that range is within bounds */
    if (((num_entered == LONG_MAX || num_entered == LONG_MIN) && errno == ERANGE)
      || (errno != 0 && num_entered == 0)) {
        printf("number found is out of range.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   

    printf("strtol() found: %ld\n", num_entered);

    /* prints out excess characters found */
    if (*endptr != '\0') {
        printf("Further characters found after number: %s\n", endptr);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```